# PHP Mock a class used as instance another class

Tags: codeigniter, phpunit

i guess if it is possible to make a mock on a class, in a way any instance of the class have same behaviour on a method

```
class Calculator
{
    public function add($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}

class TestCalculator {
    protected Calculator $cal;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cal = new Calculator();
    }

    public function add($a, $b){
        return $this->cal->add($a,$b);
    }
}


        $calculator = $this->getMockBuilder(Calculator::class) ->getMock();
        $calculator->expects($this->any())
                   ->method('add')
                   ->will($this->returnValue(6));

        //ok method return 6
        $this->assertEquals(6, $calculator->add(100, 100));

        $test = new TestCalculator();
        // //failed method return 200
        $this->assertEquals(6, $test->add(100, 100));
```

in the test test->add failed because test->add call TestCalculator::cal->add
and the mock is not acive anymore. is there a way to do that or overload a class:method for any instance?

Comment: You have to use Dependency Injection, in the constructor create a parameter it being the calculator class, or use `app(Calculator::clas)` instead of `new Calculator()`.

Comment: I don’t understand your comment app() can you give no more details ?

Comment: I am really sorry, I thought it was laravel, not codeigniter, my bad !